# What options are set when exim commands are given through a heredoc?

Tags: vim

I have a bash script that runs (something like) the following command:

```
vim -E <<EOT
call Myfunc()
EOT
```

where `Myfunc()` is defined in my .vimrc. I've discovered that using the heredoc (but not simply calling it with `-E` and entering commands manually) causes vim to skip loading my .vimrc, consequently setting compatible mode (causing other problems down the road).

I can load my .vimrc manually if I have to, but I'm assuming I don't know a priori where it is, so I'd like to let vim do the work.

Does using the heredoc make vim set some other option (`-u NORC`, say), which I can just unset  to get normal behaviour?

I'm in Vim 7.3, if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving arguments to vim through a heredoc is equivalent to taking input from stdin:

```
vim -E -
call Myfunc()
qa!
```

This starts vim in silent mode (see `:help -s-ex`) and only loads plugins specified by the `-u` argument. To load all plugins, write the ex command to a file and use that file for input:

```
cat <<EOT > input.vim
call Myfunc()
qa!
EOT

vim -E input.vim
```

(I added `qa:` to force vim to exit after running `Myfunc()`.)